# VS 2019 optimize code in release mode broken?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

For me it looks quite strange, and like a bug.
This code in Release mode in Visual Studio 2019 provides infinite loop.

```
class Program
{
    private static int _a;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _a = 1;
        while (_a == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_a);
            _a = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

`volatile` or `Thread.MemoryBarrier();` (after `_a = 0;`) solves the issue. Don't think I had such issue with VS2015. Is this correct behavior? What exact part is optimized?

Comment: Which .NET Framework or .NET Core SDK version? Which platform when .NET Core?

Comment: @nkr I use .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: I can reproduce this. It certainly looks like a bug - there's no multithreading here, so it shouldn't be necessary to use Volatile or anything like that! (Reproduced with x64, .net 4.8, Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.3, release build)

Comment: @Sinatr in Release mode?

Comment: This should definitely be reported to Microsoft. It's a nice simple repro of a pretty nasty error.

Comment: can only reproduce with x64, AnyCPU runs fine

Comment: works fine as well if you initialize the variable:
private static int _a = 0;

Comment: Disabling "Prefer 32-bit" with AnyCPU is also making problems.

Comment: @Alexey: Do you have a 32-bit Windows?

Comment: @nkr you are right, disabling "Prefer 32-bit"  with Any CPU results in issue. Locally I have x64 windows

Comment: I have reported this bug to Microsoft and linked the bug report back to this thread. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/715760/jit-compiler-bug-incorrect-caching-of-loop-variabl.html

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem with VS 2017. Changing "Any CPU" to x64 and it's infinite loop with `0`. Works fine with x86 (Windows 10, 64-bit). Bug appears from .Net Framework 4.0 and upwards, e.g. 2.0 doesn't have it.

Comment: [I've also reported this on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26417) (which seems to be the correct place for the bug report!)

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue on vs 2019 community 16.2.4, release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue.

A fix for it is in the works and will be available shortly.

Comment: Is this a comment?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ It's a response from a contributor to the codebase; implicit in this post is an acknowledgement that the report above is indeed a bug rather than intended behavior.

Comment: Fixed in CoreCLR 3.0 with https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/26952